# Cannot chain Map.fromList with zip

Tags: haskell

executing the following Code in ghci:

```hs
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
f = Map.fromList . zip
```

will give the following error:

```
<interactive>:16:20: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[b0] -> [(a, b0)]’ with ‘[(k, a1)]’
      Expected type: [a] -> [(k, a1)]
        Actual type: [a] -> [b0] -> [(a, b0)]
    • Probable cause: ‘zip’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘zip’
      In the expression: Map.fromList . zip
      In an equation for ‘f’: f = Map.fromList . zip
    • Relevant bindings include
        f :: [a] -> Map.Map k a1 (bound at <interactive>:16:1)
```

I would have expected f to a function of type `[a] -> [b] -> Map a b`
What's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you compose `zip` with another function it means you're considering it as a function

```
zip :: [a] -> ([b] -> [(a,b)])
```

So the function you compose it with would need to have an argument of type `[b] -> [(a,b)]`. But the argument of `Map.fromList` is only the `[(a,b)]` part, i.e. it requires that the other argument also has been applied already.

There are a couple of ways around this:

- Use the function in uncurried form. That has the behaviour you seem to have expected here – i.e., `Map.fromList . uncurry zip` typechecks – however it means the whole thing will also take the list arguments in tuple form, which is kind of scorned upon by Haskellers

  ```
  f :: Ord a => ([a], [b]) -> Map.Map a b
  f = Map.fromList . uncurry zip
  ```

  Of course you could “undo the uncurrying”

  ```
  f :: Ord a => [a] -> [b] -> Map.Map a b
  f = curry $ Map.fromList . uncurry zip
  ```

  but that's a bit silly.
- Do the composition with the version of `fromList` that composes itself after another argument. This can be done as an operator section of the composition operator:

  ```
  f = (Map.fromList . ) . zip
  ```

  The same thing can also be achieved by tapping into the `Functor (c->)` instance

  ```
  f = fmap Map.fromList . zip
  ```

  I'm not a fan of either of these.
- Simply make at least one of the arguments point-ful.

  ```
  f keys = Map.fromList . zip keys
  ```

  That's what I would recommend.

Comment: Just wanted to say I appreciate the formatting of `zip`'s signature

Comment: @Iceland_jack I envy your eyesight. Oh, for the days before I needed bifocals...

Comment: The types will shrink until morale improves

Comment: Hey, I didn't have a lot of time sooner. Thanks for the answer. But I don't understand the fmap solution. For it to work `fmap Map.fromList` needs to be of type `[b] -> [(a, b)]` but it is of type `f [(a, b)] -> f (Map a b)` so why does that work?

Comment: @Uzaku, not for it to work `fmap Map.fromList` needs to be a function that takes an *argument* of type `[b] -> [(a, b)]`. And the type you correctly quote for `fmap Map.fromList` unifies with that when `f` is the "function functor" - ie in this case when `f a` is defined as `[b] -> a`. Also  note that, for this functor, `fmap` is just function composition (`(.)`), which is what is mentioned at this point in the answer. Like @leftaroundabout, I wouldn't recommend actually writing it this way - but you can.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Ok, I think I vaguely understand. But now, the fmap approach seems kinda elegant to me. What's the reason you dislike it?

Comment: well opinions differ, but personally I definitely prefer `(.)` to `fmap` in a situation where `fmap` is simply being used as another name for `(.)`, as in the situation we're discussing here - because `(.)` is more explicit as to what you're actually doing. In any case, all these forms are less explicit and therefore worse than the simple formulation at the bottom of the answer.